# Empty value is resulting in a NaN result

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My form displays `NaN` when the input fields are empty. Can you help me to handle this issue? Here’s my code:

```js
function dailyRate () {
    var monthlyRate = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
    var months = 12;
    var workingDays = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);
    var totalDailyRate = (monthlyRate * months) / workingDays;
    document.getElementById("totalRate").innerHTML = Math.round(totalDailyRate);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#mainForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $("#txt2, #txt1").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+A
             (e.keyCode == 65 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+C
             (e.keyCode == 67 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
             // Allow: Ctrl+X
             (e.keyCode == 88 && e.ctrlKey === true) ||
             // Allow: home, end, left, right
             (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 39)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
                 return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
        if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
             e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="mainForm" id="mainForm" action="" onsubmit="return dailyRate()" method="post">
<input type="text" id="txt1" name="text1" placeholder="monthlyrate">
<input type="text" id="txt2" name="text2" placeholder="workingDays">
<p id="alerttext"></p>
<button>Submit</button>
<p id="totalRate"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: `NaN` is not an error. What should it do instead?

Comment: Yes, how can i manage this NaN when you entering an empty value?

Comment: You still haven’t answered my question. _What should it do instead?_ Handle it _how_? Manage this _how_? What precisely should happen when the input fields are empty?

Comment: I want to display an error if i entered an empty value in input fields.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the value is `NaN` or not. If it is `NaN`, you can set the value to 0 or show an error message:

```
var textField1 = document.getElementById("txt1");
var textField2 = document.getElementById("txt2");

var monthlyRate = parseInt(textField1.value);
var workingDays = parseInt(textField2.value);

if (isNaN(monthlyRate)) {
    textField1.value = 0;
    monthlyRate = 0;
}

if (isNaN(workingDays)) {
    textField2.value = 0;
    monthlyRate = 0;
}
```

OR:

```
if (isNaN(totalDailyRate)) {
    document.getElementById("totalRate").innerHTML = "Please enter valid numbers";
} else {
    document.getElementById("totalRate").innerHTML = Math.round(totalDailyRate);
}
```

**Suggestion**: If you use `<input type="number">`, modern browsers display controls for increasing and decreasing the number in the input field.

Answer (score 0):

The function `parseInt()` returns NaN if the content is not a number, in your case, if the control is empty, the return of getElementById will return an empty string. So probably you should perform some validation before using it, like:

```
 var monthlyRate = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt1").value);
 var months = 12;
 var workingDays = parseInt(document.getElementById("txt2").value);

 if (isNaN(monthlyRate) || isNaN(workingDays)) {
    document.getElementById("totalRate").innerHTML = 'No value';
    return;
}
```

In the example above, if any of the values are invalid, the totalRate will display 'No value'.

Comment: okay it worked but i have another if condition that I wrote awhile ago ` if (monthlyRate == null && workingDays == null) {
window.alert("Please Enter a value");
}`

but it does not work.

Comment: I don't know how you wrote it, but `document.getElementById` doesn't return null if the control is empty. You could do something like `function checkEmpty(id, field) { if (document.getElementById(id).trim() === '') { alert(field + ' has no value'); return false; } return true; }`